# Box2D collision callback

Tags: c++, opengl, box2d, collision-detection

I have two Bodies in my game that I have declared as follows:

```
b2Body* actor;
b2Body* brick;
```

Both of them are `b2PolygonShape` bodies. And there fixture declaration is as follows:

```
b2FixtureDef actorFixture;
b2FixtureDef brickFixture;
```

Now I am trying to get the information of collision and I want to confirm whether both of them collided or not. I thought I can do It by comparing the fixtures of two bodies by `GetFixture()` with actorFixture and brickFixture in `BeginContact` but i found out that it cannot be done this way! I am sorry if my question is stupid but I am learning collision detection and finding it really tough. I read the articles on it, but  still my logic is not clear. Can you help me in letting me know How can I achieve what I have mentioned above?

In the beginContact I want something like this:

```
void Callback::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
std::cout << "Begin Contact" << std::endl;
b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

if((bodyA==actorFixture||bodyB==brickFixture)
        &&   (bodyA==brickFixture||bodyB=actorFixture))
    score++
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a body with fixture which will never be equal. 
You should compare the given body pointers with the actor and brick body pointers :

```
if((bodyA==actor && bodyB==brick)
        ||   (bodyA==brick&& bodyB=actor))
    score++
}
```

Note that I also changed the condition so either `body A` equals `actor body` AND `body B` equals `brick body` OR the other way around. Otherwise the condition will never be fulfilled since `body A` (or `body B`) cannot be an `actor body` and a `brick body` at once

Comment: Okay I thought the fixtures should be compared. There is one more issue. This condition does not evaluate to true, although the bodies are colliding with each other.

Comment: hmm, does bodyA pointer address is the same given to the actor body ? (i.e. you do not copy the objects in some way)

Comment: Oops my bad! I was giving the wrong pointer! its working fine now! Thanks man! Developers at stack overflow deserve millions of thanks and appreciation for helping the beginners out! Thumbs up!

Comment: Happy to be of help :) ... and don't hesitate asking questions. No question is stupid!

Comment: Okay. So my brick is falling on my actor and I want to disable the collision after it hits the actor once. Like I want the score to increment on hitting the brick only once! And i have multiple bricks falling from random positions with different timing. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Take the fixture of the desired body and set its sensor property to false. I don't think its safe doing so in the callback method so try doing it after calling the step() method by using a boolean flag or something like that